# CheckedListBox.CheckedItems() Returning Object type instead of contents like MSDN shows

Tags: c#, datagridview, checklistbox

In attempting to run a statement that removes rows from a DataGridView's Table when the contents of said DataGridView's cell, TABLE_NAME, contents match that of one of the objects from my chklst_Selected_Tables.CheckedItems. So in short I check an option on the CheckedListBox, call the below function, and the row from the DataGrid's table that matches the text on said checked option is removed.\

```
    Public Sub Disable_Tables(ByVal chklst_Selected_Tables As CheckedListBox, ByRef dg_Queued_Tables As DataGridView)
    If Not (chklst_Selected_Tables.CheckedItems.Count = 0) Then
        For x As Integer = 0 To chklst_Selected_Tables.CheckedItems.Count
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dg_Queued_Tables.Rows
                If chklst_Selected_Tables.CheckedItems(x).ToString = row.Cells(0).Value Then
                    dg_Queued_Tables.Rows.Remove(row)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

In the code above, when i reference the .CheckedItem method for my CheckedListBox it returns the object type
Immediate Window:

`?chklst_Selected_Tables.CheckedItems(0)
{System.Data.DataRowView}
    System.Data.DataRowView: {System.Data.DataRowView}`
chklst_Selected_Tables was populted by using the the .DataSource property if that makes any difference in the long run.
Thank you for any insight.

Comment: You can't modify the collection in a for-each loop.

Comment: Exactly - the normal technique in such a case would be to interate with a for loop in the opposite direction (from count-1 to 0) so that removal og an item will not disturb the iteration.